# When will all functional car mods be unlocked?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm rushing the main story to finally upgrade my cars with the biggest engine/Turbo/etc.

I'm @ 50% progress. Will it take until the end of the main storyline?

PS: I'm not talking about the design-mods, only things that increase the speed/handling/acceleration and similar attributes. :)

Comment: Mine updated after just a few main heist missions if I recall. Some time after the Jewel Store and/or Merryweather cargo ship heists.

Comment: @DavidYell: True, I unlocked everything without noticing it, lol. What I can say now: People @50% progress have EVERYTHING unlocked, not just the functional parts. Thx for the hint, didn't notice that from my mails.